# Posting data from Arduino to a server in JSON format

Tags: json, post, arduino

I tried to upload some manual data to the server in JSON format via my Arduino device. I used SIM800(Seeduino library) for net connection. The program is compiled and running without any error. But my manual data are not transmitted to the server. Below is my code. Help me to fix that.

```
#include <gprs.h>
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>

char url="http://test.server.com";

GPRS client;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
while(!Serial);
Serial.println("Connection Test...");
client.preInit();
while(0!=client.init()){
  delay (1000);
  Serial.println("init error");
  }
  while(!client.join("MYAPNAddress"));//I used airtelgprs.com
  {  
  Serial.println("error");
  delay(2000);
  }
  Serial.print("IP Address is");
  Serial.println(client.getIPAddress());
  Serial.println("INit succeess");

  }
  void post()
  {
   char data="{  \"vehicleId\" : 1,  \"version\" : 1, }";
   Serial.println(data);
   Serial.println("POST/page/listener/insert HTTP/1.1");
   Serial.println("HOST:testserver.com");
   Serial.println("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
   if(0!=client.connectTCP(url,80)){
    Serial.println("TCP error");
    goto STOP;
   }
   if(0!=client.sendTCPData(data)){
    Serial.println("sending error");
    goto STOP;
   }
   STOP:
   client.closeTCP();
   return 0;
  }
 void loop() {
  post();
  delay(200);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not allowed to comment yet :-)

- There is at least a space missing between "POST" and the URL
- you need \r\n after each line (use print(), not println())
- you need and empty line between the header and the payload
- you need some JSON, at some point, as the payload

Comment: Thanks for the answer..

Actually the Sim card is not been initiated by the device.. So the data connection is not being established.. If you have any idea to fix that.. Please suggest..